# Custom WordPress Login

Tags: php

I have a custom WordPress login Form and when I enter correct details it adds 
?login=failed to the url but if I try login again with the wrong credentials it then becomes ?login=failed?login=failed is there anyway to reset this.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed') { ?>
    <div style="background-color: #5ab547; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 13px 0px;">
        Invalid Username or Password, Please try again.
    </div>
<?php } ?>




<div class="loginForm dark">
      <?php
         if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:

            if(isset($_GET['redirecturl']) &&  $_GET['redirecturl'] == 'followup') {
                $redirectto = "http://yaregroup.com".$_GET['url'];
                    $args = array(
                        'redirect' => $redirectto, 
                        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
                        'label_username' => __( 'Email Address' ),
                        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
                        'remember' => true
                    );

            } else {

                    $args = array(
                        'redirect' => 'http://yaregroup.com/bankrollNew/dashboard/', 
                        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
                        'label_username' => __( 'Email Address' ),
                        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
                        'remember' => true
                    );
            }

             wp_login_form( $args );
         } else { // If logged in:
            echo '<div class="btn btnCommand">';
             wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
             echo '</div>';
             wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
         }
         ?>
      <div id="forgot">
      <a href="http://yaregroup.com/bankrollNew/passreset/">Forgot Username or Password</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where do you add this parameter to the url? Can you show us the code?

Comment: it adds to the end of the URL on wordpress login if it fails. Does that answer your question or do you need more?

Comment: This isn't the code that is causing your problem. It is something in the server side code that checks if the login was good or bad and then redirects the user. It is probably redirecting them to the current URL + ?login=failed so it adds on another ?login=failed each time. You just need to add a check in the redirect code.

Comment: please show your login code, we cannot help you with the code if you wont show it.

Comment: You are perfectly correct Joseph. Its how I do the check though that I am strumped on. I am not a PHP guy and I know its somethign very simple but I can't seem to work it out

Comment: added my code above.